# installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition is ignored

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to maintain the Splash Screen visible until a boolean variable tells the app which screen should navigate to. That boolean variable needs to be loaded, and after that, the Splash Screen should be removed.

However, now that is not the case. The welcome screen is displayed for a short time (1s aprox.), and then the app navigates to the screen that it's supposed to if the user has completed an onboarding process. What I'm doing wrong?

**SplashScreenViewModel:**

```
class SplashScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val preferences: Preferences
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow<RequestState>(RequestState.Loading)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    private val _startDestination: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("welcome")
    val startDestination: State<String> = _startDestination

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val onboardingCompleted = preferences.readOnboardingCompleted()
            if (onboardingCompleted) {
                _startDestination.value = "overview"
            } else {
                _startDestination.value = "welcome"
            }
            _isLoading.value = RequestState.Success()
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var splashScreenViewModel: SplashScreenViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
            splashScreenViewModel.isLoading.value is RequestState.Loading
        }

        setContent {
            HealthTheme {

                val startDestination by splashScreenViewModel.startDestination
                val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) }
                ) { paddingValues ->
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavHost( // TODO: Navigation just for testing (to be improved)
                        navController = navController,
                        startDestination = startDestination
                    ) {
                        // Composables with their routes...
```

**RequestState:**

```
sealed interface RequestState {
    data object Loading : RequestState
    data class Success(val data: Any? = null) : RequestState
    data class Error(val message: String) : RequestState
}
```